# Possible Research Topics

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology, research, differential-algebra

I am a mathematics undergraduate in the last semester of my junior year. I am looking for research projects involving differential equations, topology, and abstract algebra and any combination thereof that will have some type of publishable results. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Where might begin if I wanted to look into discrete subgroups?

Comment: A classical introduction is the book [Discrete subgroups of Lie groups](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642864285) by Raghunathan. But there are many other lecture notes.

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll check that resource out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm finishing my undergraduate studies to obtain a math degree and I've been proposed to study minimal surfaces for my final project. It's a topic in differential geometry which relates with algebra, variational analysis and topology, so I think it may be of your interest. In any case I recommend to talk to your teachers and find out about their projects, because they will be your mentors in your first steps in research

Comment: Great, I will look into that. Thank you.